# How I write a clean condition from a "complex" combinations of conditions with && or ||

Tags: javascript, typescript, conditional-statements, coding-style, refactoring

For example, a have two statement conditions:

First, something similar to

```
const condition1 = value === '' && value1 === '' && value2 === '' && valu3e === '' && value4 === '' && value5 === ''
```

and second conditions more simple like

```
const condition2 = value === 'error'
```

and my if the statement has the two like this:

```
if (condition1 || condition2) {
....
}
```

Has any way to make this better than the actual implementation?

Comment: Do you really have 6 enumerated `value` variables? Use an array instead.

Comment: Extracting each logical expression result to a variable seems pretty good. It's the usual solution for having extremely big logical expressions. Is there a problem with using that?

Comment: Estou tentando extrair isso de cada lógica, mas fico errado em algo porque são mais de 6 expressões. Mas agora está tudo bem, obrigado pessoal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First condition :

```js
const value = '',
  value1 = '',
  value2 = '',
  value3 = '',
  value4 = '',
  value5 = '';

const condition1 = [
  value,
  value1,
  value2,
  value3,
  value4,
  value5,
].every(x => x === '');

console.log(`Condition1 : ${condition1}`);
```

---

If you can refactor the values to be an array it would be better.

```js
const values = [
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
];

const condition1 = values.every(x => x === '');

console.log(`Condition1 : ${condition1}`);
```

---

Altogether

```js
const value = '',
  value1 = '',
  value2 = '',
  value3 = '',
  value4 = '',
  value5 = '';
  
if ([
  value,
  value1,
  value2,
  value3,
  value4,
  value5,
].every(x => x === '') || value === 'error') {
  console.log(`Condition : true`);
} else {
  console.log(`Condition : false`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why not simply :

```
if ( (value === '' && value1 === '' && value2 === '' && valu3e === '') 
   || value === 'error' 
   ) {
  /// ...
}
```

?

Comment: I using this, but the condition is more largest that from my question, because this I try to refactor her. But thanks.